# Layout with 2 columns and 2 rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a **.container**
with 2 columns and in the second column **.right** I want to have 2 rows
but the first row **.content** should use the remaining space

this is the HTML markup

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="content">content</div>
        <div class="footer">footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the CSS

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 400px; /* the remaining space  in the screen will be nice */
}

.left {
    width: 300px;
}

.right {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.content {
    align-self: stretch; /* this is not doing anything*/
}

.footer {

}
```

and this is how it should look

```
+--------+----------------------+
|        |                      |
|        |                      |
|        |       content        |
|  left  |                      |
|        |                      |
|        +----------------------+
|        |       footer         |
+--------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a full height flexbox `container`:

- nest a column flexbox inside for the `right` element,
- use `flex-grow: 1` on `content` to occupy remaining space.

See demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction: row; <-- omit this, its default */
  height: 100vh; /* full height */
}

.left {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.right {
  flex-grow: 1; /* occupy remaining space */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* column flexbox */
  border: 1px solid;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1; /* occupy remaining space */
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="content">content</div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox works just fine here but I wanted to point out this is also a perfect situation for CSS Grid.  With grid you can get rid of the extra container div.right.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>



.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 100px; /* change the 100px to your desired height of the footer*/
    grid-template-areas: 
      'left content'
      'left footer';
    height: 400px; /* height OP selected */
}

.left {
  grid-area: left;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
}

.footer {
 grid-area: footer;
}
```

A [CodePen](https://codepen.io/LouBagel/pen/GawvOX) just for fun.

Answer (score 0):

[Working example jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7brncmk/)

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 100VH;
}

.left {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.right {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.content {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-bottom: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;

}

.footer {
    border: 2px solid;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Would think min-height:100vh would be better